# Computing the second derivative of interpolated data

Tags: numpy, scipy, differentiation

I have a 1-D data of 100 `(x,y)` pairs.  Let's call the array of `x` as `data_x` and the array of `y` as `data_y`.

To get `f(x)`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
f = interp1d(data_x, data_y, bounds_error=False, fill_value=np.nan)
```

To get `f'(x)`:

```
def fp(x):
    return (f(x+eps) - f(x))/eps

# where eps is a very small number, for example 1e-3
```

To get `f''(x)`:

```
def fpp(x):
    return (fp(x+eps) - fp(x))/eps
```

To plot, I used the following plot commands:

```
numpoints = 100
plot_x = np.linspace(-5, 0, numpoints)
plt.plot(plot_x, f(plot_x))
plt.plot(plot_x, fp(plot_x))
plt.plot(plot_x, fpp(plot_x))
```

When I plot those 3 functions, I get a problematic jaggy line for the second derivative.  How do I get rid of these?

[image]

Comment: For straight line interpolation each 'block' will have a constant gradient. The second derivative within each block is therefore zero. It depends what your data is but it seems to measure alternative points at the change in gradient and a second point within the block, which will be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a twice differentiable interpolator, use e.g. CubicSpline : `CubicSpline(x_data, y_data).derivative(2)`  is a callable object representing the 2nd derivative. Or if you want the derivative inplace, use `CubicSpline(x_data, y_data)(xnew, 2)`